# Копирование данных с одного масива в другой

Tags: c#, массивы

Добрый день.
Есть класс

```
public class BaseOrganization
{
     //Some Data
}
```

и

```
public class Organization : BaseOrganization { }
```

Есть масcив данных

`BaseOrganization[] baseOrg` заполненный данными.

и  пока что пустой

`Organization[] org`

Вопрос: как скопировать данные с baseOrg в org ? Нужно только в цикле перебирать все данные или можно как-то скастовать и присвоить?

Спасибо.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Во-первых, не пользуйтесь массивами, C# давно вырос из версии 1.1.

Затем, вы *не можете* получить просто так экземпляр производного класса по экземпляру базового класса, в конце-концов, в производном классе *больше* семантики. (Пример: вы не можете, имея произвольную машину неизвестной марки, скастить её в Lamborghini, вам возможно понадобится разобрать её на детали и пересобрать.)

Таким образом, у вас должен быть метод создания `Organization` из `BaseOrganization`. (Например, конструктор, если никакой новой семантики *на самом деле* нет.) Значит, ваш код будет таким:

```
List<BaseOrganization> baseOrg = ...
// или BaseOrganization[]
List<Organization> org = baseOrg.Select(bo => CreateO(bo)).ToList();
```

На место `CreateO` подставьте свой код.

Comment: @Telsystems: Если очень хочется получить на выходе массив, а не `List<>`, напишите `.ToArray()` вместо `.ToList()`. Но я бы посоветовал `List`, он во всех аспектах круче.

Comment: Хотелось бы отметить, что в данном случае происходит копирование ссылок, а не объектов.

Comment: а что по поводу list.AddRange(secondList); ?

Comment: @Anxis: Копирования вообще не происходит, объект базового типа не может быть превращён в объект производного типа.

@jimpanzer: Не выйдет, у вас же объекты в `secondList` несовместимого типа.

Comment: Сорри, невнимательно прочитал вопрос.